# how to create a rectangle object of a particular width using itext

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a pdf using the itext library.
I want to create a pdf where the width of pdf is fixed at 3.020cms and height is auto adjustable according to the text

I found that we need to create a Document object of itext where we can specify the page size like:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The first parameter as I found is a Rectangle object of itext.
In the api of Rectangle I could not find any readymade constuctor where I can only specify the width to a particular value and set height as auto.
Could anyone suggest how can i create a pdf of where width is fixed to 3.020cms but height is auto.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *height as auto* - What do you mean by *auto*? Page height is a number.

Comment: I mean height of the pdf should be according to text  i.e text should wrap beyond 3.5cms width ( width of pdf is fixed 3.5 cms ) and depending on length of text the height should vary

Comment: Height as auto is a concept that doesn't exist in PDF, so you'll have to use a workaround. I've answered this question before. I'll look for my answer and close the question as a duplicate if possible.